# How I can change tab titles text dynamicaly after create activity

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-viewpager

I create tab activity like this:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(new WithdrawalFragment(),"a");
adapter.addFrag(new DepositeFragment(), "b");
adapter.addFrag(new AllTransactionFragment(), "c");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

So how I can get tab-titles and update it's text Dynamically from my activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find this solution:

first define a custom View and inflate and set it's parameters.
then add this view to destination tab.

```
View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_tab_text, null);
TextView myTitltle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
myTitle.settext("Dynamic Text");
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);  // I wanted to change tab0 text
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization time dynamic settings items of the viewpager, https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator,this demo can help you.